# React_Native Using Post Request with Fetch isn't work(PHP is work normaly)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If I click the button , there was no error message but doesn't work (doesn't add item)

What i want to do is.

Send a POST request, having a 4parameters.

This is fetch in React-Native

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetch('http://user.dothome.co.kr/process.php?mode=insert',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    lot: '99',
    project_start: '2020-05-03',
    project_end: '2020-05-03',
    workdays: '0',
  }),
}
)}
```

And this is a process.php code,which take a request.

I'v checked this process.php works normally.

i think the problem is at the above fetch..

```
switch($_GET['mode']){
    case 'insert':
        // Escape special characters, if any
        $lot = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['lot']);
        $project_start = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['project_start']);
        $project_end = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['project_end']);
        $workdays = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['workdays']);
        $result = mysqli_query( $conn, "INSERT INTO tb_cobbitty (lot, project_start, project_end, workdays) VALUES ('$lot', '$project_start', '$project_end', '$workdays')");
        header("Location: list.php");
        break;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does the request send? What do you get back as the response?

Comment: no need to get back,
I intended to send  4 parameters via POST, to process.php,
And process.php adds 4 parameters in SQL database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to pass the mode insert as a POST param on the body?

It's seems to be a little confuse to pass part of your data in GET and part with POST at the same request.

The fetch syntax is correct, therefore try to use the http verb GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc.. for each request to make things get more concise and clear.

Comment: 'mode' : 'insert',
    'lot': '99',
    'project_start': '2020-05-03',
    'project_end': '2020-05-03',
    'workdays': '0',

Comment: like this, i put the 'mode' in the body

Comment: But it still doesn't work,
Anyway! Thanks for you help!

Comment: @novous0000 I would suggest you to try use user Postman to find out the error! It's the best tool for it

Comment: @novous0000 I have followed you advice, you saved my day. Thks!